# cakephp validation

Tags: validation, cakephp

I use validation in model like this

```
'email' => array( 
            //'UniqueMail'=>array('rule' => array('checkEmailUnique', 'email' ),'message' => 'mail is used'),
            'email'=>array('rule' => 'email','message' => 'mail not valid'),
            'notEmpty'=>array('rule' => 'notEmpty','message' => '*'),
        )
```

and this validation for field email 
but in some other form idon't want to check the unique mail validation . 
how i can solve this?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** add that rule to your $validates array.

Create a `beforeValidate()` [callback in your model](http://book.cakephp.org/view/682/beforeValidate).

In the `beforeValidate()` callback check for the presence of a flag in the form data (something like `$data[$this->alias]['checkMail']`. If the flag is set, then add the email validation rule to your `$this->validates` array. This will prevent you from validating against that rule unless you specifically tell the model to do so.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
'email' => array(
            'mail' => array(
                'rule' => array('email', true),
                'required' => false,
                'message' => 'Not correct e-mail!'),
            'unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'E-mail was registered!')),
```